# How do you distinguish centralized and decentralized databases?

Tags: database-design

What is the difference between centralized and decentralized databases?

Answer (score 1):

> "[In Decentralized Database, a big database is partitioned as per business requirement in such a way that each smaller database represents a specific data subject](http://www.geekinterview.com/kb/Decentralized-Database.html)"